# Корректна ли пунктуация заголовка: "Эго. Любить или бояться?"

Tags: пунктуация, заголовок

Или лучше оформить так: "Эго: любить или бояться"? С двоеточием и без вопросительного знака. Насколько я знаю, вопросительный знак при оформлении статей нежелателен.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой  В вопросе высказывается сомнение о корректности использования "?" в заголовке и предлагается вариант с двоеточием и без "?". Таким образом, в кавычках должен быть вопрос, как и написал автор первоначально, а после кавычек он не должен повторяться. http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/165-oszp

Comment: Юлия спрашивает, правильно ли **без** "?". Что после кавычек он не должен повторяться, я и так знаю.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой  Всё верно. Но в заголовке вопроса — вопрос: "нужен ли (может ли быть) вопросит. знак в заголовке?". Чтобы не впадать в излишнюю полемику, хотелось бы спросить Юлию.

Comment: Интересует ответ на вопрос о корректности данной пунктуации: "Эго. Любить или бояться?"
Также ответ на вопрос о возможности такого оформления: "Эго: любить или бояться".

Comment: Если вопросительный знак не поставить, то желаемый смысл (вероятно, раскрывается спорная тема, причём **вопрос** ставится автором) может измениться: возникает ощущение, что автор заявляет об окончательном **решении** вопроса, который ставился другими.

Comment: Юлия, перефразируйте как-то, пожалуйста, чтобы было противопоставление, а то вы задаёте два противоположных вопроса без переходной интонации. Например, *"или лучше оформить так..."* вместо "возможно ли".

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец: похоже, я зря всё-таки запятую поставил после "например", да? Повёлся на то, что он длинный.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой  Не могу вспомнить где. А, в комментарии выше? Нет, все нормально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пунктуация корректна.

В справочнике Лопатина читаем:

> § 24. **После именительного темы, сопровождаемого вопросительным
>   предложением, ставится точка**: Научный потенциал. Как им распорядиться?
>   (газ.); Гастроли в Москве. Что они значат? (газ.); Разум на других
>   планетах. Каков он? (журн.).
>
> Примечание. Допустимо используемое в практике печати и написание со
>   знаком двоеточие: Студенческий быт: каким ему быть? (газ.).
>
> Если после именительного темы стоит вопросительная часть конструкции,
>   которая также представляет собой форму именительного падежа, то
>   ставится тире: Сценарий — произведение или полуфабрикат? (газ.);
>   «Зеленая революция» — легенда или реальность? (газ.). В таких случаях
>   возможна подстановка слова это. Ср.: Парапсихология — это трюк или
>   реальность? Действительность или фикция? (газ.).
>
> Примечание 1. **Допустимо используемое в практике печати и написание со
>   знаком двоеточие перед вопросительной конструкцией. Например: Стадион:
>   «цех здоровья» или футбольная арена ? (газ.); Литературное
>   произведение: символ или модель ? (газ.).**
>
> Примечание 2. Данные структуры с именительным темы отличаются от
>   двусоставных предложений с подлежащим и сказуемым в именительном
>   падеже интонацией: интонация именительного темы схожа с интонацией
>   конца предложения (понижение тона и пауза), тогда как подлежащее в
>   двусоставном предложении не фиксирует конечной паузы. Ср.: Стадион —
>   цех здоровья (подлежащее и сказуемое). Здесь подлежащее и сказуемое
>   связаны воедино интонацией утверждения.

https://orfhographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=110#pp110

Так что оба варианта допустимы - и с точкой, и с двоеточием, но вопросительный знак в данной фразе должен остаться, это же вопрос, а не утверждение. И кто Вам сказал, что в заголовках вопросительный знак нежелателен? Не видела такого ограничения.